# sign in link to azure active directory return blank page

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I cannot sign in to Azure active directory from my web app and also from the azure.microsoft.com my account sign in.
trying to click on the link (within my app or from microsoft website)return a blank page. 
does anyone know of a problem?

Comment: There's an issue with azure atm : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: Thanks @MilenPavlov - didn't know this status page for azure services.

Comment: Glad I can help - I've been experiencing these issues for the past hour now, hope it will be back up soon.

Comment: Users are reporting the issue in [here](http://downdetector.com/status/office-365/map/) too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are having issues. Look at http://status.azure.com/